# OBIEE configuration

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have my current OBIEE installed in a linux server under oracle directory. Now the current warehouse (ODI and data storage ) has moved to AWS.Can I change any configuration file within this installation to point to the warehouse tables in AWS instead?

I know my articulation of the problem is bit confusing. I will be happy to clarify if needed.

Thanks

Comment: You're running an on-premises OBIEE and want to connect to an AWS-hosted Oracle DB is that it?

Comment: @Christian Berg Yes

Comment: The question was more on OBIEE side. Where in OBIEE do I change the database details. I have not installed OBIEE ever. So I dont know where exactly to change the database connection details.

Comment: Updated the answer below

Comment: Hey Christian, I now understand that the connection pool gives me the details about obiee metadata. Still I could not find the info on where to find the connection details for database which holds the actual data thats being reported.  I mean the data warehouse database details which OBIEE is reporting from.

Comment: That IS the connection pool. The connection pool object contains connectivity information to go to data sources and grab information so it can be analyzed. In your words: connection pools point to the DWH database where your OBI is reporting from.

Comment: thanks Chritian Berg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcutting your assumed answer:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.Oracle.html#CHAP_GettingStarted.Connecting.Oracle

Creating connection pools: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/bi.1111/e10540/conn_pool.htm#BIEMG1262